# Sampling 3 out of 20 numbered balls from a box, what is distribution of max number drawn?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The tittle may be a little misleading as I couldn't sum up the problem in one sentence.

There are 20 numbered balls in a box and we pick 3 without replacement and without caring about the order that we picked them.

Let Random Variable $X$ express the largest number out of the three.

> $-$ Find $p_{X}(x) = P(X=x),$ for all the possible $x$'s.
>
> $-$  Then, find the cumulative distribution function: $F_{X}(x) = P(X \leq\ x) $

The set of all possible outcomes consists of ${20\choose3}=1140$ elements.

All the possible $x$ values are $:  {3,4,5,...,19,20}$.

There are too many possible $x$'s to calculate the density of $X$ for each one individually, so I am trying to find a general expression for that. Also, I think the $2nd$ question will become easier if the first one is solved.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at a specific value, say $P(X=12)$.  For the highest ball to be $12$, you have to pick one ball from the set $\{12\}$ and two balls from the set $\{1,2,3,\dots,11\}$.

So there should be a total of $1\cdot {11\choose 2}$ ways to do this.

You can generalize this idea to continue the problem.

Comment: So the number of elements in the density of $X$ must be ${X-1\choose2}$ for every $x$ ?

Comment: In R: `x=3:20; choose(x-1, 2)` returns `  1   3   6  10  15  21  28  36  45  55  66  78  91 105 120 136 153 171` for numerators, denom 1140. $So, \;yes.$ (In my simulated answer, `154` is the only incorrect value, should be `153`.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ denote balls drawn from the urn without replacement. You seek to compute $$\Pr\left(\max\left(X_1,X_2,X_3\right) \leqslant x \right) = \Pr\left( X_1 \leqslant x ,X_2  \leqslant x ,X_3 \leqslant x \right)$$

The latter probability is the probability of choosing 3 marked balls (those whose numbers are $\leqslant x$) out of total $N = 20$ balls, see [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution):
$$
  \Pr\left( X_1 \leqslant x ,X_2  \leqslant x ,X_3 \leqslant x \right) = \frac{ \binom{x}{3}}{\binom{N}{3}} [ 3 \leqslant x \leqslant N ] = \frac{x (x-1)(x-2)}{N (N-1)(N-2)} [ 3 \leqslant x \leqslant N ] = \frac{x (x-1)(x-2)}{6840} [ 3 \leqslant x \leqslant 20 ] 
$$
Then 
$$
  \Pr\left(\max(X_1,X_2,X_3)=x\right) = \Pr\left(\max(X_1,X_2,X_3) \leqslant x\right) - \Pr\left(\max(X_1,X_2,X_3) \leqslant x-1\right) = \frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{2280}  [ 3 \leqslant x \leqslant 20 ] 
$$

Here is a quick verification with simulation in Mathematica:

[image]

Comment: TeX broken. Fixable?

Answer (score 1):

In the Answer of @paw88789 (+1) you have a method that
can be generalized to find the PDF of the maximum $X.$

Below is a simulation in R, based on a million picks of three balls
from the urn, giving probabilities that are accurate to 2 or 3
places. Multiplying by ${20 \choose 3} = 1140$ and rounding
to the nearest integer "almost" gives numerators of the fractions
with 1140 as denominators--likely a few of them wrong. [Notice that simulated probability $P(X = 12) = 55/1140$ is
exactly correct.] But this output should give you
a helpful reality check on your analytic answers.

```
 m = 10^6;  pop = 1:20;  n = 3;  x = numeric(m)
 for (i in 1:m)  {
   take = sample(pop, n);  x[i] = max(take) }
 round(table(x)/m, 4)
 ## x
 ##      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11 
 ## 0.0009 0.0026 0.0052 0.0087 0.0134 0.0182 0.0245 0.0315 0.0391 
 ##     12     13     14     15     16     17     18     19     20 
 ## 0.0483 0.0577 0.0683 0.0799 0.0925 0.1052 0.1191 0.1350 0.1498 

 round(1140*table(x)/m)
 ## x
 ##  3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20 
 ##  1   3   6  10  15  21  28  36  45  55  66  78  91 105 120 136 154 171
```

Comment: I am just a beginner, I don't know how this simulation came up. Isn't there a general type to describe the outcome for every $x$ ?

Comment: Simulation is just an independent way to verify the PDF. General formula in Answ from @paw88789 using a conbinatorial argument: $p(x) = {x-1 \choose 2}/1140$, for $x = 3,4,\dots,20.$

Comment: Oh, ok thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise, you can use a simple EXCEL macro to find the values:

```
Sub Macro1734572()
'
' Macro1734572 Macro
'
CONT = 1

For I = 1 To 18
For J = I + 1 To 19
For K = J + 1 To 20

Cells(CONT, 1) = I
Cells(CONT, 2) = J
Cells(CONT, 3) = K
Cells(CONT, 4) = WorksheetFunction.Max(Cells(CONT, 1), Cells(CONT, 2), Cells(CONT, 3))
CONT = CONT + 1

Next K
Next J
Next I

CONT1 = 1
For L = 1 To 20
Cells(CONT1, 7) = L
Cells(CONT1, 8) = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(1140,  4)), L)
CONT1 = CONT1 + 1
Next L

'
End Sub
```

This macro can be upgraded and this new version Works with numbers between 3 and 50 numbered balls. It was added an INPUTBOX Command.

```
Sub Macro1734572b()
'
' Macro1734572b Macro
'
Columns("A:H").Select
Range("H1").Activate
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("A1").Select

10 Q = INPUTBOX("ENTER Q VALUE (Q MIN = 3 - Q MAX = 50)", "Q")

   If (Q > 50 Or Q < 3) Then
   MsgBox "False"
   GoTo 10
   End If

CONT = 1

For I = 1 To Q - 2
For J = I + 1 To Q - 1
For K = J + 1 To Q

Cells(CONT, 1) = I
Cells(CONT, 2) = J
Cells(CONT, 3) = K
Cells(CONT, 4) = WorksheetFunction.Max(Cells(CONT, 1), Cells(CONT, 2), Cells(CONT, 3))
CONT = CONT + 1

Next K
Next J
Next I

CONT1 = 1
For L = 1 To Q
Cells(CONT1, 7) = L
Cells(CONT1, 8) = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(19600, 4)), L)
CONT1 = CONT1 + 1
Next L
'
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that would work, though it would be better if I could get a general type that would work for every $x$.  Any idea about that?

Comment: @George.K - I updated my answer with a new routine that can work with up to 50 numbered balls.